# if curl getinfo for HTTP CODE is not returning a code?

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a normal curl call to a webservice and I grab the return HTTP code through

```
$code = curl_getinfo ($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

It does return me $code as 200 - which is good.
But logging the curl calls now from a week, there where few calls to the same webservice which didn't return anything! so basically I am getting $code as blank.

Can someone tell me what should be going wrong under those scenarios, and if can debug it more!?

Thanks,
Tanmay

-----------------------Update-------------------------

Thanks everyone for the info. Yes I was also thinking the same, its not reaching the server. I will update my code with to get curl_error && curl_errno and will update you guys soon.

Thanks again.

---------------------- Update 2---------------------------------------------------------
I did update my code to return me the error no 7 -  couldn't connect to host.
I did logged all the curl calls, so basically around 90-98% of curl calls are executing good. But only 1-2% of curl calls are not able to find the host! Can anyone tell me what could be the reason? and How I can prevent it?

Thanks again,
Tanmay

Answer (score 4):

If the cURL HTTP code returned nothing (aka '0'), that means the cURL operation failed for some reason. It would be beneficial to capture the `curl_error` in your logs as well as it might give you more insight to was happened in those cases (if they happen again).

[PHP: curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

When you are logging it, check if it is blank, if it is, log more, using this function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

My guess would be that its not able to reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve a `curl_getinfo` from a request that failed. Check the result from `curl_exec` to determine whether an actual HTTP request has been performed.

A connect timeout or anything of the likes is a "failed request". In that case `curl_exec` returns FALSE (as stated in the [curl_exec Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a situation where no HTTP headers were returned -- i.e. the request was unsuccessful.  Perhaps the server's internet access was down, or for some other reason inaccessible.

If you look at the [`curl_getinfo` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), it suggests checking whether an error has occurred in the example:

```
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
}
```