# cURL Error No : 7 - Couldn't connect to host!

Tags: php, curl

I did ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513073/if-curl-getinfo-for-http-code-is-not-returning-a-code) around last week and did got some info on how to proceed with curl call errors.

My scenario  -  I am doing a cURL call to a webservice, and I would say around 90% of times the curl calls are successful for the same calls, but it fails for many! I did some googling which said , the server might be blocking my calls!

My Question

- How I would be certain that my calls are blocked? (Note : the webservice servers are internal to the company, so I might get a help from administrator)
- Is there any way that i can debug on my end!? or would need help from administrator!?
- How should I resolve it to make sure 100% calls are successful
- And just in case its a windows server (not sure which version) for the webservices

Comment: @jtanmay - error 7 is more likely related to network, or target server not available during curl

Comment: @ajreal - I did a continuous ping to the servers, and all were successful, no packets were lost!

Comment: @jtanmay - ping does not mean request page is successfully on the target server

Comment: If cURL doesn't give you useful debug info, stop using it. There is the PHP-internal HttpRequest, PEARs HTTP_Request, and Zend_HTTP, which all provide much more sensible APIs.

Comment: @mario: I don't see how you can get more useful than "I tried to connect here, but that was not possible". cURL doesn't know why the target server refuses the request, it just reports what it finds. No other webservice setup is going to be any different on that.

Comment: @BillyONeal: cURL isn't a HTTP connection library. It is a multi-protocol library (SSH, IMAP, FTP, LDAP, DICT, POP3, just to name a few). As thus it provides a lowest-common-denominator API for all it's backend protocols and returns a generic failure code regardless of the socket error. I'm sure one of the HTTP libs can outdo it; besides providing more sensible HTTP header defaults.

Comment: @everyone - Would there be any logging on the webservice servers, which would indicate that it blocked the call!? or there is no way to get ahead on this!?

Comment: @mario - i'll try using HttpRequest, and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @jtanmay: Every successful HTTP connection should be in the `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. Else it's a Firewall issue, or research if `mod_evasive` blocks frequent requests.