# Check if an image exist using HTTPS

Tags: php, image, url

I am just wondering if there is a way to check if an encrypted image exist over https.

I am using this code below to check whether an image exist. It will return `200` if it does, and `404` if it doesn't. But this only work on image URL that does not contain `https`.

```
function exists_url($uri){
            $ch = curl_init($uri);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_exec($ch);
            return $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);

        }
```

If I try to verify this url ( `https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTup5KSMveqkgrDKZR6p-0ANhPkJ7srbJOlKR78DUqqh85I_3MUrw` ) it gives me a result of 0 instead of 200 or 404.

I have thought to use `getimagesize()` function to accomplish this task. But even this function only works for image that is not send over HTTPS.

Comment: First of the image is not encrypted in any way. The "encrypted" part of the URL probably refers to the method of connection being HTTPS (also known as SSL/TLS). Secondly try [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to get a decent error message back from curl.

Comment: Then your solution is?

Comment: Do `echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);` after `curl_exec($ch)` and post back the error message.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed0"

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using SSL/TLS you must point cURL to a valid CA Certificate bundle. The bundle must be in `.pem` format. You can obtain such a bundle from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/.

Next you need to tell cURL to use your CA bundle. You can do this with the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path_to_file/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Comment: This is good to verify if the url exist. But what if you want to determine if it is an image or not? using 'http://www.google.com' as a url will return 200 as well as a valid url.

Comment: @user3135626 As you have tried, you can use the `getimagesize()` function, however I would rather use [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) as it doesn't need to download the entire image. **You must make sure OpenSSL is enabled in your PHP installation so that you can use HTTPS as a stream.**

Comment: Nope, iI am getting this error : exif_imagetype(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP

Comment: @user3135626 Do `phpinfo()` and check for openssl support. If you don't find it you need to enable it, otherwise as stated in my previous comment, HTTPS streams won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply deactivate the verify of peer with

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

So you have not to worry about nothing.

**Watch out**: @user555 answer is better for security purposes

Answer (score 0):

A response code of 0 from Curl typically means there was an error connecting to the server or something along those lines (See [PHP cURL HTTP CODE return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0) and countless other questions).

I did however run this code myself using PHP 5.5.x and it returned a 200 as expected. getimagesize() not working also leads me to think it's most likely a problem with curl or php on your system, what versions of them do you have?