# Curl Post snippet with PHP is working on localhost but not at my hosting webpage

Tags: php, curl, xmlhttprequest

i'm using the same snippet of code both locally and online.
At my localhost server i get HTTP status code of 200 and i have no problem.
When i use the same piece of code at my webpage which i'm currently being hosted i get HTTP code of 0.

Here is the snippet i'm using for my HTTP call.

```
$curl = curl_init();

// Set the options
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxx:xxxx/xx");

// This sets the number of fields to post
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// This is the fields to post.
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Data");

//execute the post
$session = curl_exec($curl);
//Echo Http Response Code
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have curl installed on your server ?

Comment: I'm using curl for other purposes too and i had no problem with my server.
So i guess that it's installed.

Comment: do this `print curl_error($curl);`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0

Comment: If you connect with the server, then you can get a return code from it, otherwise it will fail and you get a 0. So if you try to connect to "www.google.com/lksdfk" you will get a return code of 400, if you go directly to google.com, you will get 302 (and then 200 if you forward to the next page... well I do because it forwards to google.com.br, so you might not get that), and if you go to "googlecom" you will get a 0 **(host no found),** so with the last one, there is nobody to send a code back.

Comment: i get `Failed to connect to ww.wwwwwwww.com port 8090`
with `print curl_error($curl);`

Could it be the port?
Because as i told you, the same url and code works from localhost.