# PHP curl always returns http_code 0

Tags: php, curl

Hello StackOverflow community, I've encountered a problem when I try to use cURL methods on PHP. I tried with this sample code:

```
$html_brand = "www.google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"),
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($response)."</pre>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

And it always ends with an error, displaying it on screen:

> Return code is 0 Recv failure: Connection was reset

Or this error, when trying to reach any site with https:

> Return code is 0 Failed to connect to www.google.com port 443: Timed
>   out

This are my settings:

- Windows 7 Professional 32 bit
- Apache 2.4.12
- PHP 5.6.11

Is it a code error or any server configurations I have not considered?

The `HTTP_HOST` value in Apache is `localhost:8080`, which I'm not really sure if it has anything to do with my problem, but maybe it's worth noting.

Thank all of you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall logs to see if the request made it that far?

Comment: is this question, then I can't figure out what is difference b/w answer and question, look http://stackoverflow.com/a/10228476/2558525

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL HTTP CODE return 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0)

Comment: @RowlandShaw, firewalls are deactivated on my Windows system

Comment: @MubinKhalid, I took my sample code from that answer to test if it could solve my problem as well, obviously it didn't. I added a few lines like `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, but they did not make any difference. I used it as a sample in this question because it seems to be the most coherent, complete and simple test code that I have found in the last few hours, and it would be nice to make it work for further coding on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a custom function, that works fine for `GET, POST and ajax` requests.

So here it's

```
    function spider($header = array(), $referer = false, $url, $cookie = false,$post = false)
    {
        if (!$cookie)
        {
            $cookie = "cookie.txt";
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
        if (isset($header) && !empty($header))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if (isset($referer) && $referer != false)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        } else
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        }
        //if have to post data on the server
        if (isset($post) && !empty($post) && $post)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        } //endif
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        print_r($info);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($info['http_code'] == 200){
            return ($data);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

so, parameters are,

`$header` =>  Headers to send to server, this should be `associative array`.

`$referer` => Referrer to current page(if any).

`$url` => URL that you want to get.

`$cookie` => cookie file, should be on the same level where the calling script is.

`$post` => data to post (if any)

I tested this function as follows.

```
echo spider(FALSE, FALSE, 'https://www.google.com/ncr');
```

here is header that I got.

```
Array
(
[url] => https://www.google.com/
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 1665
[request_size] => 701
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 20
[redirect_count] => 1
[total_time] => 2.215
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 9024
[speed_download] => 4074
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.437
[redirect_time] => 1.7
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] => 
)
```

and here is snapshot of this request.

[image]

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately it did not solve my problem, I tested your function the same way you did and I got an array with most values on 0: `Array ( [url] => https://www.google.com/ncr [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 20.218 [namelookup_time] => 0.015...`, total_time and namelookup_time are the only elements with other value than 0. I don't really think that my problem is code-related now but I may keep your function as testing code for the future :)