# Curl crashing frequently when using with php

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl 7.42.1 with php 5.6.16,
It crashing frequently and during debug it give http_code=>0.
I have tried by increasing timeout but still it gives http_code 0.
I rebuild curl and it getting fix automatically, and crash again after some days.
I have tried latest version of curl 7.46.0 but 7.42.1 seems more stable.
Using curl on CentOS release 6.7

What could be reason behind frequently crashing ?

here is curl options which i am using

```
$this->curlArray=array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR=>false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE=>true,            
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT=>true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=> 3,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>  3            
    );
```

Comment: Can you post in your question curl command probably there is some issue with options, so we will be able to help you?

Comment: @Armen i have updated question

Comment: Try to check first answer from here  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0

Comment: @Armen Yes, i have checked all questions before posting this,
I think there is no issue with code because its works perfectly when i rebuild curl, and after sometime it starts returning http_code 0