# Php Curl is not working curl_getinfo returns array where all variables are zero

Tags: php, curl, apache2, owncloud

I have this test code:

```
<?php

$html_brand = "https://google.com";
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
} else {
    echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($response)."</pre>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

And page result (I have put \n before variable name for better readability) is:

```
Return code is 0 Array ( 
[url] => https://google.com 
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0 
[header_size] => 0 
[request_size] => 0 
[filetime] => 0 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0 
[namelookup_time] => 0 
[connect_time] => 0 
[pretransfer_time] => 0 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 0 
[speed_download] => 0 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => -1 
[upload_content_length] => -1 
[starttransfer_time] => 0 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
[primary_port] => 0 
[local_ip] => 
[local_port] => 0 )
```

What is wrong here? I could not figure out why curl is not working on my machine. Internet is working, command line curl is working very fine.
I'm on PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14, 
and this is curl section from phpinfo()[image: phpinfo screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried dumping curl error `var_dump(curl_error($ch));`?

Comment: var dump is exactly string(0) ""

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0

Comment: but that answer doesn't help me, because I don't know what is wrong. curl doesn't return anything useful to determine what's wrong

Comment: There's likely nothing wrong with your code (I tried it, straight copy paste worked) you're likely getting blocked by a firewall or something.  A status code of 0 usually means the server was never reached.  You could try `ping google.com` from your server's console.  Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0

Comment: it works perfectly : $ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.214.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.214.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=21.3 ms
64 bytes from fra16s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.214.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=20.4 ms
I am really shocked what is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that I have disabled curl_exec function in php.ini. In apache2 log:

```
PHP Warning:  curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /var/www/***/html/test.php on line 18
```

Enabling it in php.ini did the trick!