# MailChimp class using __construct

Tags: php, function, class, constructor

I'm trying to create mailchimp class to be used later, however I have problems with __constructor function. Without constructor, by just using `add($data, $list)` its working fine, but with __constructor this just output `(int)0`, when it should be `(int)200`...

There is 2 lists to chose from, add, get and delete functions...

Curl works WITHOUT constructor, when I combine constructor to add function, everything works just fine, issue is with the constructor

Class file:

```
class mailchimp
{

    private $apiKey = '<apiKey>';
    private $list1 = 'listOneId';
    private $list2 = 'listTwoId';

    function __construct($data, $list)
    {
        $listId = $list === 'list1' ? $this->list1 : $this->list2;

        $memberId = md5(strtolower($data['email']));
        $dataCenter = substr($this->apiKey,strpos($this->apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/' . $memberId;
    }

    function add() {

        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $data['email'],
            'status'        => $data['status'], // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
        ]);

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $this->apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $httpCode;
    }

    function get($email)
    {
```

File where executed(add and get):

```
include_once 'mailchimp.class.php';

$data = array(
  'email' => 'my@example.com',
  'status' => 'subscribed'
);

$mc = new mailchimp($data, 'list2');

var_dump($mc->add());
```

Or

```
$data = array(
   'email' => 'my@example.com'
);

$mc = new mailchimp($data, 'list1');

var_dump($mc->get());
```

Comment: It's unclear to me which sample use of the class is failing, could you clarify?

Comment: `$mc = new mailchimp($data, 'list2');
var_dump($mc->add());` then constructor does not work, if I execute this without constructor and move constructor insides to function add itself, it works... Like I execute this with `add($data, $list2)` without constructor, it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL HTTP CODE return 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0)

Comment: @JohnV. curl works without constructor

Comment: Have you looked at the curl error output as described in the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to read up on [scoping in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), `$url` from the constructor doesn't persist beyond it's function scope. You'll need to place it into the object as a property in order to use it in other functions in the class.

An example of what I mean:

```
class A {
    private $url;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->url = "http://someurl.com";
    }
    public function useURL(){
        //Do something with $this->url
    }
}
```