# curl_getinfo() showing empty parameters before and after executing

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I've got a setup (Laravel) that has been working for years now, but suddenly something changed and the curl_setopt wont work anymore. When the curl is executed it retruns a cURL Error 55 (Failed sending http request).

I use php 5.6.

Here is the setting of my curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    if (!$ch) {
        die("ERROR: cURL initialization failed.  Check your cURL/PHP configuration.");
    }

    // - then set the cURL options; to ignore SSL invalid certificates; set timeouts etc. 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, SERVER_URL);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); <---This is an array

    $this->Response = curl_exec ($ch);

    // Check for any connection errors and then close the connection.
    $curlError = curl_errno($ch);
    $curlErrorText = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the output of curl_getinfo() before and after curl_exec() -- it is the same:

```
[url] => -------This is an HTTPS link
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 0
[local_ip] => 
[local_port] => 0
```

Why would the info be empty, even if everything is set. Like I said, this use to work before. I have not changed anything on the server.

Comment: I believe here is an answer for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0

Comment: `http_code` 0 means its not hitting the server correctly. Make sure you are hitting the correct server from your client side.

Comment: Could this mean the the URL has changed? Or perhaps that the receiving process has changed?

Comment: This could mean many number of things.Some firewall rule on your end OR theirs is preventing the connection. Or any in between. Make sure the url is accessible from the server by pinging it

Comment: I get "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" when I curl -Is the URL.

Comment: But when I try to ping it I get "Name or service not known".

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it this way.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $end_point);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); //Content-Type:application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return [$result, $info];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain what must be changed for the code to work like your example so that users don't have to compare the code from the question with yours?