# cURL call return status code 0 on the SERVER

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm trying to make an API call using curl method.

I've tried the same call on MAMP using a demo project from the creators of the app that I want to integrate and it's all PHP code... now on the server I've just included the PHP Library and tried to make the call in PHP but I don't know why I got status code 0.

```
private function _cURL($url, $data, $request, $headAccept) {
        $headers = array($headAccept, "Authorization: Basic " . $this->hash);

$ch = curl_init($url);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
if ( !empty($data) ) {
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
}
if ( !empty($request)) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// debugging
$isDebug = self::DEBUG_ON_ERROR;
if ( !empty($isDebug) ) {
    $debug = array(
        'URL: '     => $url,
        'data: '    => $data,
        'headers: ' => $headAccept,
    );
    echo '<pre>' , print_r($debug, true), '</pre>';
}

return $ch;
```

}

I don't know what should I do.. because the status is only 0.. nothing like 403, 404, etc.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

```
        $ch = $this->_cURL($url, $data, $request, $headAccept);        
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

**EDIT 2**
After calling `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` the response is:

```
(
    [url] => https://ws.smartbill.ro:8183/SBORO/api/estimate
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.007306
    [namelookup_time] => 0.007255
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

**EDIT 3**

I downloaded the project from production and tested on localhost using `php artisan:serve` and works... so is a server problem..but I don't know what to do...

Comment: hello, edited post

Comment: `var_dump($return);` check the result , why are u not using `$return = curl_exec($ch);` inside your function, move this inside your function and return result not `$ch`

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0 maybe that helps.

Comment: @devpro is bool(false)

Comment: ok, using local host or LIVE server?

Comment: you can check curl error by `curl_errno($ch)`

Comment: @devpro on LIVE is false... on live returns string(69) "{"errorText":"","message":"","number":"1234","series":"dddd","url":""}"

Comment: @tanaydin hmm, I got Connection refused;

Comment: from where `$this->_cURL($url, $data, $request, $headAccept);` are u calling from same class?

Comment: @devpro yeah same class, different methods

Comment: If this works on one server, but not another, and you are getting "Connection refused" then the computer having trouble may be locked behind a firewall or the destination of the curl request may be blocking that computer.

Comment: Can you give the actual `URL` that you are hitting?

Comment: https://ws.smartbill.ro:8183/SBORO/api/estimate

Comment: Can you do a `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch))` and see what all you get?

Comment: @vivek_23 post edited

Comment: @presagefu Saw just now. Request never reached that URL. This should surely be a block. `Maybe` your IP is black listed or it's a firewall problem.

Comment: @vivek_23 I don't think that the IP is black listed... But I don't know about firewall..what can I do about that? I have accces to cPanel.

Comment: @presagefu does ping to that site from your command prompt work? You have access to cPanel of whom?

Comment: @vivek_23 I've tried to do a ping and got 'Unknown host'. But I've downloaded the project on localhost..and worked..so is a server problem.. cPanel of the project that use cURL

Comment: @presagefu Contact your host provider about this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this function that I have

```
public static function get($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    // dd($info);

    curl_close($ch);
    $result =  json_decode($result, true);
    return $result;
}
```

It works perfect fine on my laravel project.

See if it help!