# cURL showing no error but code is not working

Tags: laravel, curl

Here is the cURL code i am implementing in php

```
$url = 'https://encodingapi.alientech.to/api/kess3/decode-read-file/user1?callbackURL=https://backend.ecutech.gr/callback/kess3';
        
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data', 'X-Alientech-ReCodAPI-LLC:'.$token));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $data = "readFile=".public_path('obd1');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
        {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
        }        
        curl_close($curl);

        exit;
```

now the problem is that it is working fine but $result variable has empty string in it.

Comment: did you test the api with postman and it returned something ?

Comment: I can not actually. I can only check on the server.

Comment: then do some research. use other tools on the server to get the information needed to start debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

So an empty string is adequate for a successful POST to an API.
Use

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

to check.

Comment: it is return the $httpCode is 0.

Comment: you'll want to debug your connection https://stackoverflow.com/q/10227879/2959798