# I don't know what's wrong with my cUrl request (http status 0)

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting an http status of 0 even though it worked on my computer.

Details :
I hosted a website on 000webhost and then, i uploaded my files

I tried everything i found on StackOverflow but nothing works

I did a curl_getinfo() on my request and here's what i got:

```
content_type :
http_code : 0
header_size : 0
request_size : 0
filetime : -1
ssl_verify_result : 0
redirect_count : 0
total_time : 7.0E-5
namelookup_time : 0.004153
connect_time : 0
pretransfer_time : 0
size_upload : 0
size_download : 0
speed_download : 0
speed_upload : 0
download_content_length : -1
upload_content_length : -1
starttransfer_time : 0
redirect_time : 0
redirect_url :
primary_ip : 20.74.64.100
certinfo : Array
primary_port : 443
local_ip :
local_port : 0
```

Here's my PHP code to test what caused the error to occurred :

```php
<?php
    $tokens = json_decode(file_get_contents("tokens.json"), true);
    $url = "https://api.****************************************";
    $request = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "apiKey: " . apiKey
        ]);
    $res = curl_exec($request);
    foreach(curl_getinfo($request) as $i => $j){
        echo "$i : $j</br>";
    };
    curl_close($request);
?>
```

Comment: 1) Check network / firewall settings on your hosting

2) Add some kind of error loging.  And check if it gives better error. 

if(curl_errno($request)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($request);
}

Comment: @AliAmjid it gives me this `Failed to connect to <IP address>: Network is unreachable` EDIT : I just saw that 000webhost they block for outbound traffic to prevent phising attacks (thx you anyway)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP cURL HTTP CODE return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov No, the thing that solved my problem was the fact that 000webhost was blocking outbound traffics